# javax.faces.FacesException, when user hits return

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I have a JSP which is a included JSP inside another JSP.

During runtime, if I keep the cursor inside a textbox and hit return, I get following exception.

The input field in my child JSP is as follows.

```
    <input type="text" id="mask" name="mask" value="<%=mask%>" size="30"/>
```

Exception:

```
javax.faces.FacesException
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:388)
    at com.soa.console.faces.myfaces.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
    at com.soa.common.console.CrossSiteScriptingValidator.doFilter(CrossSiteScriptingValidator.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.SecuritySessionServletFilter.doFilter(SecuritySessionServletFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.SessionValidatorFilter.doFilter(SessionValidatorFilter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.RequestAttributesFilter.doFilter(RequestAttributesFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.ParameterToSessionPersisterFilter.doFilter(ParameterToSessionPersisterFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at com.soa.transport.jetty.j2ee.HttpContextAppHandler.doHandle(HttpContextAppHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.soa.transport.jetty.j2ee.HttpContextAppHandler.doHandle(HttpContextAppHandler.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:120)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:416)
    at com.soa.console.faces.config.impl.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:124)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:384)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getContextRelativePath(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:907)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:962)
    at com.soa.jsp.dev.wizards.routing.manage_005fprocess_005factivity_005fholder_jsp._jspService(manage_005fprocess_005factivity_005fholder_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
    at com.soa.dev.filter.JspCompilationFilter.doFilter(JspCompilationFilter.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at com.soa.transport.jetty.j2ee.HttpContextAppHandler.doHandle(HttpContextAppHandler.java:278)
    ... 48 more

Caused by:

java.io.IOException
    at com.soa.transport.jetty.j2ee.HttpContextAppHandler.doHandle(HttpContextAppHandler.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:120)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:416)
    at com.soa.console.faces.config.impl.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:124)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:384)
    at com.soa.console.faces.myfaces.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
    at com.soa.common.console.CrossSiteScriptingValidator.doFilter(CrossSiteScriptingValidator.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.SecuritySessionServletFilter.doFilter(SecuritySessionServletFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.SessionValidatorFilter.doFilter(SessionValidatorFilter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.RequestAttributesFilter.doFilter(RequestAttributesFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.ParameterToSessionPersisterFilter.doFilter(ParameterToSessionPersisterFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at com.soa.transport.jetty.j2ee.HttpContextAppHandler.doHandle(HttpContextAppHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getContextRelativePath(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:907)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:962)
    at com.soa.jsp.dev.wizards.routing.manage_005fprocess_005factivity_005fholder_jsp._jspService(manage_005fprocess_005factivity_005fholder_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
    at com.soa.dev.filter.JspCompilationFilter.doFilter(JspCompilationFilter.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at com.soa.transport.jetty.j2ee.HttpContextAppHandler.doHandle(HttpContextAppHandler.java:278)
    ... 48 more

Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getContextRelativePath(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:907)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:962)
    at com.soa.jsp.dev.wizards.routing.manage_005fprocess_005factivity_005fholder_jsp._jspService(manage_005fprocess_005factivity_005fholder_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
    at com.soa.dev.filter.JspCompilationFilter.doFilter(JspCompilationFilter.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at com.soa.transport.jetty.j2ee.HttpContextAppHandler.doHandle(HttpContextAppHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:120)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:416)
    at com.soa.console.faces.config.impl.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:124)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:384)
    at com.soa.console.faces.myfaces.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
    at com.soa.common.console.CrossSiteScriptingValidator.doFilter(CrossSiteScriptingValidator.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.SecuritySessionServletFilter.doFilter(SecuritySessionServletFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.SessionValidatorFilter.doFilter(SessionValidatorFilter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.RequestAttributesFilter.doFilter(RequestAttributesFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at com.soa.common.console.ParameterToSessionPersisterFilter.doFilter(ParameterToSessionPersisterFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at com.soa.transport.jetty.j2ee.HttpContextAppHandler.doHandle(HttpContextAppHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where's the root cause of the excpetion?

Comment: I apologize. I have updated the exception now.

Answer (score 0):

Look closer at the root cause (the bottommost exception):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getContextRelativePath(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:907)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:962)
    at com.soa.jsp.dev.wizards.routing.manage_005fprocess_005factivity_005fholder_jsp._jspService(manage_005fprocess_005factivity_005fholder_jsp.java:176)
```

You've a `..manage/process/activity/holder.jsp` file which uses a `<jsp:include>` whose `src` has caused `NullPointerException` in some way during resolving the context relative path.

I can think of 2 possible causes:

1. The `src` itself is `null`. That may happen on a dynamic include like follows:

   ```
   <jsp:include src="${someBean.someInclude}" />
   ```

   If you indeed have such an include, you need to make sure that its `src` never evaluates as `null`.
2. The webapp's runtime classpath is polluted with arbitrarily downloaded `jsp-api.jar` file from a different servletcontainer make/version which conflicts with the servletcontainer's (in your case, Jetty's) own internal libraries.

   If you indeed have done like that, you'd need to get rid of them all and make sure that the runtime classpath is free of duplicate older versioned servletcontainer-specific libraries. See for a related answer also [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706)